# Flutter detect killing off the app

Tags: flutter

I would like to know whether detect killing off the app is possible or not. 
Let’s say in a chat app, I was able to get timestamp when user leaves the chat room by using onWillPop. 
But if user killed off the app directly from the chat room, it won’t be fired off. So is there a way to detect that?
Or any suggestions to get timestamp different way?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

See also https://flutter.io/flutter-for-android/#how-do-i-listen-to-android-activity-lifecycle-events

You can listen for inactive, paused, and detached.
This might be a bit too early but usually, it's better to do some cleanup a bit too early and too often than not at all:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(LifecycleEventHandler(
    detachedCallBack: () async => widget.appController.persistState(),
    resumeCallBack: () async {
      _log.finest('resume...');
    }));
```

```
class LifecycleEventHandler extends WidgetsBindingObserver {
  LifecycleEventHandler({this.resumeCallBack, this.detachedCallBack});

  final FutureVoidCallback resumeCallBack;
  final FutureVoidCallback detachedCallBack;

//  @override
//  Future<bool> didPopRoute()

//  @override
//  void didHaveMemoryPressure()

  @override
  Future<void> didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        await detachedCallBack();
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        await resumeCallBack();
        break;
    }
    _log.finest('''
=============================================================
               $state
=============================================================
''');
  }

//  @override
//  void didChangeLocale(Locale locale)

//  @override
//  void didChangeTextScaleFactor()

//  @override
//  void didChangeMetrics();

//  @override
//  Future<bool> didPushRoute(String route)
}
```

**Edit**

With this [pull request](https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/11913) on 4th November 2019, the enum `AppLifecycleState.suspending` was renamed to `AppLifecycleState.detached`. If you are using Flutter with a version prior to 1.12, you must still use `AppLifecycleState.suspending`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. So in my use case, I should listen to inactive?

Comment: See https://flutter.io/flutter-for-android/#how-do-i-listen-to-android-activity-lifecycle-events

Comment: Sorry if I’m misunderstanding, only paused works for both platforms. But it says running in background. Can I handle with this when user force quit app?

Comment: I'd expect this to work, but also fire when the app is switched in background or already when the task-switcher is shown, but that usually wouldn't hurt because you shouldn't do too expensive work here anyway.

Comment: Sounds great I’ll try that out! Let me ask a final question what do you mean by “hurt”?

Comment: I mean that the event probably occurs more often that necessary. If you switch to the Android task switcher and back to the app the event will already be fired.

Comment: Oh ok but better than never! Thank you always for you help!

Comment: The detached is not the same as "killing off" or "terminating" the app. It just says that the detached will be called when the current page gets pop or calls `SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');`.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61846907/when-applifecyclestate-detached-gets-called

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer widget.appcontroller can't be found. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @AliGürelli that's custom code. You need to add your own implementation of what should happen in case of an event (I persisted the state)

Comment: Ah okay my mistake. İ haven't investigated the code but now i got it. Sorry that was really so easy:)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer but its not being called when app killed by user

Comment: @AliGürelli exactly, let me know if anyone found a way to know when app gets killed or terminated from the recent apps?

Comment: @JayMungara unfortunetly couldnt achieved it :/

Comment: this support ios?

Comment: Detach is not being called, if user close the app by force kill(by swipe)

Comment: what is FutureVoidCallback ?

Comment: @68060 I can't remember. Should probably be https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/AsyncCallback.html