# Flutter (Dart) remove firebase database Listener

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I add an firebase database Listener to my flutter project as below:

```
databaseReference = database.reference().child("community_board");
databaseReference.onChildAdded.listen(_onEntryAdded);
databaseReference.onChildChanged.listen(_onEntryChanged);
```

For Kotlin and swift of firebase, I have to remove the listener in onPause()/onDestroy(). May I know how to remove the firebase database listener in flutter?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var sub1 = databaseReference.onChildAdded.listen(_onEntryAdded);
var sub2 = databaseReference.onChildChanged.listen(_onEntryChanged);

sub1.cancel();
sub2.cancel();
```

If you have this code in a widget you can use

```
@override
void dispose() {
  super.dispose();
  sub1?.cancel();
  sub2?.cancel();
}
```

Comment: thank you , is dispose() = onDestroy() for android? How to start the listener onResume and remove listener onPause()?

Comment: `dispose()` is called when a widget is removed from the view and discarded. `onResume`, `onPause` sounds more like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52074265/flutter-detect-killing-off-the-app/52074534#52074534 (I don't know Android well)

Comment: if my listener is in repository, how can I close it ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61194277/listen-call-multiple-time