# Flutter .listen called multiple times

Tags: file, flutter, dart

I using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_uploader in my project.

**repository**

```
try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
      if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        final taskId = await uploader.enqueue(
            url:
                'https://xxxx',
            files: files,
            data: {
             ....
            },
            method: UploadMethod.POST,
            showNotification: true,
            tag: title);

        final subscription = uploader.result.listen((result) async {
          print("response " + result.response);
        }, onError: (ex, stacktrace) {
          print(ex.toString());
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      ...
    }
  }
```

When first time I call this, `uploader.result.listen` will only print once. But if I call this method again, `uploader.result.listen` will call twice. Why?

**Edit**

I have changed my code to this

**PageA**

```
  StreamSubscription<UploadTaskResponse> _subscription;
  FlutterUploader uploader = FlutterUploader();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _subscription = uploader.result.listen(
      (result) {

         // insert result to database
           .....
      },
      onError: (ex, stacktrace) {
        // ... code to handle error
      },
    );

  }

  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _subscription.cancel();
    _defectBloc.dispose();
  }
```

In page A, it has floatingActionButton. When the floating action button is clicked, it will open page B.  I will pass the `uploader` param to PageB and `bloc`, so it can listen to the `uploader`. Data able to insert into local database if I on the init page. How can I let the insert work too if I exit the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `uploader.result.listen` it'll add a subscription each time, if you call that n times, n subscription will be added.

To fix the issue, either you need to cancel previous subscription using [cancel()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/StreamSubscription/cancel.html) method or you have to add the subscription only once (In your initState and cancel in your dispose method).

Comment: I  put it below `onError`, but listener will stop working.

Comment: @Hoo: You shouldn't put it on just below. You have  make that subscription as an instance variable and when you call this method. Check whether the subscription is null or not, if not null cancel it and subscribe again. But my suggestion is to subscribe once in your code, that's the cleanest way of doing this

Comment: Can you check my post again? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have suggestion ?

Comment: @Hoo If your app is closed, you may have to use a service. Check this document https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes

Comment: And one thing, if app on foreground but in another  page, this link can help too?

Comment: @Hoo No matter whether you are on foreground or background it will work.  :)