# Flutter : Class 'DatabaseReference' has no instance method 'cancel'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting below exception while canceling Firebase listeners

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
Class 'DatabaseReference' has no instance method 'cancel'.
Receiver: Instance of 'DatabaseReference'
Tried calling: cancel()
```

Here is my code

```
var databaseRef;

databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("messages");

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _sendMessageTextController.dispose();
    databaseRef?.cancel();

    super.dispose();
  }
```

Anyone has idea why I'm getting above execptioin

If need more information please do let me know. Thanks in advance. Your efforts will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the [API documentation for DocumentReference](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DatabaseReference-class.html), there is no method called cancel on that object.

Comment: thanks for the quick response I'm following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52081047/8112541,  i want remove listener from the `DatabaseReference` is there any other way to remove it

Comment: Unless you've called `listen()`, there is nothing to `cancel()`.  That's what the question is showing you - how to cancel after the listener was started.