# Flutter :Function to know that the user exits from the ap

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any function in flutter that will be called when a user exits from the app.Just like if the user exits from the app, the app must change its active status in Firebase database

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter detect killing off the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52074265/flutter-detect-killing-off-the-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare like this inside your stateful widget

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }
 @override
  void dispose() {
   WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
   super.dispose();
 }

  @override
  didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if(AppLifecycleState.paused == state) {
     // Here you can do your firebase operation. 
     }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   //....
  }
```