# When AppLifeCycleState.detached gets called?

Tags: flutter

I've:

```
class _PageState extends State<Page> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    print('state = $state');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold();
}
```

`AppLifeCycleState` class has got 4 callbacks, 3 of them

```
- active
- paused
- resumed
```

Seems to work but `detached` never worked in any case.

I read the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/AppLifecycleState-class.html) but couldn't understand it in practical scenario, can anyone share a relevant code, when and where does it get called?

Answer (score 4):

As the doc says

> detached → const AppLifecycleState The application is still hosted on
>   a flutter engine but is detached from any host views.
>
> When the application is in this state, the engine is running without a
>   view. It can either be in the progress of attaching a view when engine
>   was first initializes, or after the view being destroyed due to a
>   Navigator pop.

You can reproduce above issue on HomeScreen only when your home widgets go in the background(Press back button of android device)

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}



class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> with WidgetsBindingObserver {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (AppLifecycleState.paused == state) {}
    print("Status :" + state.toString());
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Book'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Home Screen'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can produce above mention thing on other screens and have a call at detached, you can do by closing application programmatically on any click event of your widget

**Android:**

```
SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');
```

**iOS:**

```
exit(0)
```

Comment: Should `Navigator.pop(context)` also invoke?

Comment: That state can trigger by the system itself, not by pop.

Comment: Let's see you only have 1 Page, and when you call `Navigator.pop(context)` on it, is this not considered as system pop? Because the app does exit or doesn't it?

Comment: There is still no proper doc available for this, but the above-mentioned methods terminate the current running process which detaches UI from a flutter engine.

Comment: What if you simply press back button on that single page, isn't that counted as exit, does flutter engine not stop there? I should and must stop, but still detached doesn't get called.

Comment: It's working more on the app side when you register those callbacks,  I think you want to do some operation on poping? if yes then refer this https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data.

Comment: I can understand `Navigator.pop(context)` may work on the app side, but what is the Android's back button working on when you only have 1 page? Should it not stop the Flutter engine? If yes, then detached should get called as per the docs and if no, that means your Flutter app engine would stay on even when the user has made an exit and it will keep on consuming user's phone memory, CPU, resources and stuff like that which makes Flutter a horrible platform to work with. What do you say?

Comment: One more thing, even when I am using `SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');`, `detached` doesn't get called

Comment: @iKeepChangingName: Please have a look at the updated code,

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug. I've tests on both iOS and Android devices. You can produce **detached** state when you closed the app by pressing the back button or swiping on Android devices, it's not woking on iOS devices. Please follow this issue on [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/57594)