# How can we get callback when application killed in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, callback, hybrid-mobile-app

In Flutter, I don't get any callback when the application is killed. Now, how can I stop streaming when my application is killed?

Scenario:
I have 3 page in stack when I pressed back, Got callback in onClose method but when i reached to last page of stack and now pressed back will not get any callback.

Comment: Close stream in dispose() method!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52074265/flutter-detect-killing-off-the-app

Comment: Check this link.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter detect killing off the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52074265/flutter-detect-killing-off-the-app)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Stateful Widget and there is a dispose method, there you can dispose everything you want when application is killed.
Example:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
}

@override
void dispose() {
//something.dispose();
super.dispose();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    body: Container());
}

}
```