# flutter | detect if user force kill the app

Tags: flutter, dart

i am trying to detect if a user force quit the application on flutter. i have been looking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52074534/4862911) answer to implement it but it is not working when any user close the app by force kill. i need a callback like `AsyncCallback` for it. any solution to do that?

the solution on the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52074534/4862911) was:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(LifecycleEventHandler(
        detachedCallBack: () async => widget.appController.persistState(),
        resumeCallBack: () async {
          _log.finest('resume...');
        }));
```

```
class LifecycleEventHandler extends WidgetsBindingObserver {
  LifecycleEventHandler({this.resumeCallBack, this.detachedCallBack});

  final FutureVoidCallback resumeCallBack;
  final FutureVoidCallback detachedCallBack;

//  @override
//  Future<bool> didPopRoute()

//  @override
//  void didHaveMemoryPressure()

  @override
  Future<void> didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        await detachedCallBack();
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        await resumeCallBack();
        break;
    }
    _log.finest('''
=============================================================
               $state
=============================================================
''');
  }

//  @override
//  void didChangeLocale(Locale locale)

//  @override
//  void didChangeTextScaleFactor()

//  @override
//  void didChangeMetrics();

//  @override
//  Future<bool> didPushRoute(String route)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is there's no simple way to detect user-initiated force kill in Flutter.

Also, consider that the app can be killed by the operating system (for instance, [OOM killer](https://blog.wesleyac.com/posts/linux-kernel-oom-killer)), not just the user.

However, depending on your use case, here are two ideas that *may* detect some situations of interest.

### Signal Handling

Depending on the platform, it *may* be possible to detect some situations with [signal handling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_signal_handling). Have a look at [ProcessSignal.watch()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/ProcessSignal/watch.html).

### Clean Shutdown Flag

Suppose you want to instrument your app to collect metrics about how often users force-close the app in response to a hang. This approach uses the concept of a *clean shutdown flag*, which is some way of marking (typically using file system storage) that a "clean" shutdown has occurred. Then, the process looks like this:

1. On app startup, check the "clean" flag. If true, proceed. Otherwise, it is possible that the user force quit the app in response to a hang.
2. Set the "clean" flag to false.
3. When you receive one of the suspending lifecycle events (i.e. `inactive`, `paused`, or `detached`), set the "clean" flag to true.
4. When you receive the `resumed` lifecycle event, set the "clean" flag to false.

In other words, if the app is suspended before termination, this is considered a "clean" shutdown.

Note that there are several caveats with this approach:

1. It will only detect instances of terminations where a suspending lifecycle event does *not* occur before closure. It's possible there are classes of hangs whereby suspending lifecycle events are still called (false negatives).
2. In non-hang terminations, it relies on an assumption that the OS suspends the app before a user-initiated termination occurs (otherwise, false positive).
3. There may be race conditions related to the timing of updating the "clean" flag.

Due to these significant caveats, I've not actually attempted to use this approach. "Your mileage may vary."

Perhaps, if you tell us *why* you want to detect a force kill, someone may be able to assist with other ideas.